# Multiple File Uploads - JSF

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF 1.2 framework. Right now i am trying to implement a file upload process in which the number of files to be uploaded is controlled by the end user. Please find the below snapshot and code snippet for reference.

[image: Multiple File Upload]

**XHTML Implementation:-**

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{importWSDLBean.xsdLoopIncrementAction}" reRender="WSDLPanelGrid">
 <h:graphicImage value="/images/plus_icon.gif" />
</a4j:commandLink>

<a4j:commandLink action="#{importWSDLBean.xsdLoopDecrementAction}" reRender="WSDLPanelGrid">
 <h:graphicImage value="/images/minus_icon.gif" />
</a4j:commandLink>

<h:panelGrid id="WSDLPanelGrid">
 <c:forEach items="#{importWSDLBean.acscDataList}" var="inputFUpload">
  <t:inputFileUpload id="#{inputFUpload.id}" value="#{inputFUpload.value}" />
 </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**Java Bean Implementation:-**

```
public String xsdLoopIncrementAction() {
    if (acscDataList == null) {
        acscDataList = new ACSCDataList(new ArrayList());
        HtmlInputFileUpload htmlUpload = new HtmlInputFileUpload();
        htmlUpload.setId("upload" + (acscDataList.size() + 1));
        acscDataList.add(htmlUpload);
    } else {
        HtmlInputFileUpload htmlUpload = new HtmlInputFileUpload();
        htmlUpload.setId("upload" + (acscDataList.size() + 1));
        acscDataList.add(htmlUpload);
    }
    return "success";
}


public String xsdLoopDecrementAction() {
    if (acscDataList != null) {
        if (acscDataList.size() > 0) {
            acscDataList.remove(acscDataList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    return "success";
}
```

This implementation resets the file upload values whenever i increment or decrement the no. of file upload fields. Also when i submit the form i cant able to get the UploadedFile object (File Upload prerequisite such as Form type and Web.xml configuration is also included).

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something prevent you from using JSF 2? Primefaces ( www.primefaces.org ) has a multiple fileupload component. It is available for JSF 1.2, but development will go on for JSF 2 only.

Comment: Upgrade to JSF2 seems to be a time killer task, as we face a lot of config issues :(. Are you sure multiple file upload is available for JSF 1.2?

Comment: Quite sure, yes, although the component uses Flash (won't anymore in next Primefaces release). I wonder how your upgrade should be a time killer task, your don't have to change your configuration (you can use annotations but aren't forced to).

Answer (score 1):

If you create dinamically yours input uploads? with binding property

```
<h:panelGrid binding="#{importWSDLBean.myPanelGrid}"></h:panelGrid>
```

in your backing bean add property

```
private javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid myPanelGrid;
/**
 * @return the myPanelGrid
 */
public javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid getMyPanelGrid() {
    return myPanelGrid;
}



/**
 * @param myPanelGrid the myPanelGrid to set
 */
public void setMyPanelGrid(javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid myPanelGrid) {
    this.myPanelGrid = myPanelGrid;
}
/*change for your value upload type*/
Map<String,Object> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
public void addInputAction() {



    String key = "key"+values.size();
            values.put(key,"newValue");

    HtmlInputText input = new HtmlInputText();
 /*add input property (converter,css,etc?)*/
    input.setId("id_"+key);

    input.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression(
            "#{WSDLPanelGrid.values['"+key+"']}", new Class[0], String.class));
/*add to panel grid your input*/
    myPanelGrid.getChildren().add(input);
}

  public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String value,
        Class[] params, Class returnType) {
    FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elctx = fctx.getELContext();
    Application jsfApp = fctx.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory exprFactory = jsfApp.getExpressionFactory();

    ValueExpression valueExpr = exprFactory.createValueExpression(elctx,
            value, returnType);

    return valueExpr;

}
```

Comment: "binding" attribute links your controller to jsf view-side code and should be avoided. But you could use the same basic idea: having a List of values in your managed bean, iterated from ui:repeat in your xhtml page. Clicking on "add" just adds an item to the list.